Using On Error Resume Next statements with OLE Automation Objects
Is it possible to use On Error statements with OLE Automation Objects?
Usually in VBA when I want to suppress errors I might use the following:
On Error Resume Next
Is there some excel object method or property that I can run/set that has the same effect?
I'm trying to suppress the error dialog I get when I perform a find and replace in Excel and no results appear. For context, I have a set of excel OLEs in DOORS, and I'm trying to perform a find and replace on those objects.

On Error GoTo 0 doesn't suppress errors, it tells VBA to show an error (the famous "Debug" window). On Error Resume Next suppresses errors (and should be used wisely and only when you know what you are doing).

On Error Resume Next will not suppress errors which occur outside of VBA (that is, in the application being automated)
